# Changing between applications in a django site

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

I have 2 applications in my site:

- users
- base

The main url conf always raises urls with the appname of base/index.html
When a url action say href="login" is provided from base/index.html it automatically
searches for "base/login.html"

I want it to switch the application and search for "users/login.html"

How do I force it to switch applications either in the html href or in the urlconf. I prefer to use url conf but don't konw how to.

users/url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from emp_users.views import *
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^index/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/hr_base/index', permanent=False), name='index'),
    url(r'^new_user/$', register_user),
    url(r'^new_hr_user/$', register_hr_user),
)
```

site/urls.py : This is the main project urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^base/index$','hr_base.views.index'),
    url(r'^users/', include('emp_users.urls')),
)
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT},),# 'show_indices':True}),
)
```

site/base/templates/base/index.html

```
<a href="login">Login</a>
```

That should pointgenerate the url users/login and then access user/views.py

Comment: Probably posting your URL routing and a sample of your templates will illustrate your situation better.

Comment: There's no such thing as "switching applications". Applications aren't things that you're in, they're simply collections of functionality.

Comment: To elaborate on what @DanielRoseman said, look at this aside in the docs, ["Projects vs. apps,"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/#creating-models) which explains what django means by "application" and how it fits into your project as a whole. *"An app is a Web application that does something – e.g., a Weblog system, a database of public records or a simple poll app. A project is a **collection of configuration and apps for a particular Web site**. A project can contain multiple apps. An app can be in multiple projects."* Emphasis mine.

Comment: I got that part but what I need is for the url to actually switch. the base/ is being automatically added to the url pattern. I need a way to change that to user/

Comment: What ever url I provide, its adding base/ prefix to it. If I provide url users/new_user, its making it base/users/new_user and returning 404

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django is not adding any URLs anywhere. You are simply providing a relative URL in your template, so your browser is adding the current path to it. If you want to specify a different path, then you need to provide that full URL: `<a href="/users/new_user">`.

However you should not be hard-coding URLs in your templates in any case. You should let Django provide the full URL:

```
<a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
```

Comment: I found out how to do this. the trick is not in you python code. Its in your html links. We can use url patterns with relative urls for each application, but in your html code, you clearly give your relative urls as

/<appname>/<view url>
This solves the problem. Had to do lot of trial and error to get here.

I dint really change anything in the url conf. It works only with the html links being changed. Thanks for all the help guys. I really learnt a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^base/login/$', 'base.views.login'),
    url(r'^users/login/$', 'users.views.login')  
)
```

or 
    in main url.py file

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^base/', include('base.url'),
    url(r'^users/', include('users.url') ,
)
```